# Закрепленный внизу navbar

Tags: bootstrap

Использую навбар из bootstrap 4(просто скопировал пример), закрепив его внизу страницы.
Но как сделать, чтобы dropdown разворачивался вверх, а не вниз?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-bottom">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="nav-item dropup>
```

остальные down не менять